# Model with hair shows up black in rendered viewport shading

Tags: materials, 3d-view, shaders

First off, I am a complete beginner, and I was following a very high-altitude tutorial. So I expect there is a box that I haven't checked. Here is what I see:
[image: Rendered Viewport]
[image: Material Preview Viewport]
[image: Material]

The model is supposed to look like fabric (a puppet). In the material preview viewport shading, everything looks correct, but if I switch to rendered viewport shading (also with renders), everything with hair on it appears black. The only things I did were to delete all of the starting assets and model the puppet. I have a Nvidia GeForce RTX 3070 and 11th Gen Intel Core i9-11900k processor. I have to assume that's good enough for basic Blender modeling.

I changed the render engine to cycles. I added a couple kinds of lighting back into the scene, which seem to be illuminating the eyes properly. None of the videos or forum posts that I found with similar problems solved my problem. That could just mean I'm missing something very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the IOR back to the default 1.55 (instead of 0) and it seems to work:

[image]

Comment: I can't upvote, but that seems to be the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Krozber Just as a quick (possible) explanation: the IOR between two media is calculated as the ratio of the speed of light in one medium to that in another medium. Which means an IOR of 0 would make the speed of light 0 in one medium, hence no light would reach the camera from the surface which makes it black. But of course this is more hypothetical and I don't know how much this actually plays a role in the render engine.